# Recursive CTE with 2 tables not working in Oracle / SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

There are 2 tables `Department` and `subdepartment` which have id in common.
I am trying to recursively fetch all the ids reporting to AB directly and indirectly. BC is reporting to AB, hence 4,5,6 are indirectly reporting to AB, likewise fetching till the last id.

Tried the below recursive `CTE` query but I am getting the result of only the first level. Seems `recursive` query is not executing.

I am not sure what is wrong in the query. Can someone help me in spotting the error.

Department

```
Name     id
AB          1
AB          2
AB          3
BC          4
BC          5
BC          6
CD          7
CD          8
EF          9
EF         10
EF         11
```

Subdepartment

```
ID      Reporting
1
2
3         BC
4
5         CD
6
7
8         EF
9
10
11
```

Query:

```
With reportinghierarchy (Name, Id, Reporting, Level) As
(

--Anchor
Select A.name,A.id,reporting,0 from department A, subdepartment B
where A.id=B.id and A.name='AB'

Union All

--Recursive member
Select C.name,C.id,D.reporting, Level+1 from department C, subdepartment D
Inner Join  reportinghierarchy R
On (C.Name = R.reporting)
Where C.name != 'AB' and C.Id =D.id
And R.Reporting is not null
)
Select * from reportinghierarchy
```

Current Output :

```
Name Id  Reporting  Level
AB   1                0
AB   2                0
AB   3   BC           0
```

Expected output :

```
Name     id     Reporting  Level
AB        1                  0
AB        2                  0
AB        3       BC         0
BC        4                  1
BC        5       CD         1
BC        6                  1
CD        7                  2
CD        8       EF         2
EF        9                  3
EF       10                  3
EF       11                  3
```

Comment: I don't understand your logic.  How do any levels get assigned to rows where `Reporting` is `NULL`?

Comment: Have edited the query. When reporting is null don't have  to explode on that

Comment: Your declare and set are not valid for Oracle, so which RDBMS are you actually using?

Comment: I am trying on SQL and Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original query was actually VERY, VERY close to working. The reasons it didn't work are:

1. **You used the keyword `LEVEL` as a column name** without quoting it. In Oracle `LEVEL` has specific meaning, and using it out of context causes the parser no end of headaches. I've changed it to `LVL`, which works fine.
2. In the recursive half of the UNION **you mixed old-style and new-style joins**. This is a huge problem and should never be done. Either use "old-style" implied joins, or use "new-style" explicit joins. To keep as close to your original as possible I used implicit joins, but good coding practice says you should use explicit joins all the time.

The corrected query is:

```
With reportinghierarchy (Name, Id, Reporting, lvl) As
(

--Anchor
Select A.name,A.id,reporting,0 from department A, subdepartment B
where A.id=B.id and A.name='AB'

Union All

--Recursive member
Select C.name,C.id,D.reporting, lvl+1 from department C, subdepartment D, reportinghierarchy R
Where C.name != 'AB' and C.Id =D.id and C.Name = R.reporting
And R.Reporting is not null
)
Select * from reportinghierarchy;
```

Given the above, the following results are returned, which appear to match your desired results:

```
NAME    ID  REPORTING   LVL
AB      1   (null)      0
AB      2   (null)      0
AB      3   BC          0
BC      4   (null)      1
BC      5   CD          1
BC      6   (null)      1
CD      7   (null)      2
CD      8   EF          2
EF      9   (null)      3
EF      10  (null)      3
EF      11  (null)      3
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d6ff6/16)

Best of luck.

Comment: One more issue I am facing with cyclic reference. When the data is as follows

Comment: One more issue I am facing with cyclic reference. When the data is as follows

Comment: `ID      Reporting
1
2
3         BC
4
5         CD
6
7
8         EF
9         CD
10
11`

Comment: @EmilJoshva - please don't use comments to add information to a question. If you want to add information you should edit the question using the `edit` button just below the tags. At this point, given that this question has already been answered, I think the best choice is to ask a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, "horrible data structure" comes to mind.  This approach gets one row per "reporting" name to use for the recursive CTE portion.  It then joins the level back to the original data.

```
with ds as (
      select d.name, d.id, sd.reporting
      from department d join
           subdepartment sd
           on d.id = sd.id
     ),
     nd as (
      select d.name, sd.reporting
      from ds
      where sd.reporting is not null
     ),
     cte as (
      select ds.name, nd.reporting, 0 as lev
      from nd
      where not exists (select 1 from nd nd2 where nd2.reporting = nd.name)
      union all
      select nd.name, nd.reporting, lev + 1
      from cte join
           nd
           on nd.name = cte.reporting 
    )
select ds.*, cte.lev
from ds join
     cte
     on ds.name = cte.name;
```

Also, learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  It has been the standard syntax for decades.

Comment: I am getting the below results
`NAME ID REPORTING LEV
AB 3 BC 0
AB 2  0
AB 1  0
AB 3 BC 0
AB 2  0
AB 1  0
BC 6  0
BC 5 CD 0
BC 4  0
BC 6  0
BC 5 CD 0
BC 4  0
CD 8 EF 0
CD 7  0
EF 11  0
EF 10  0
EF 9  0
EF 11  0
EF 10  0
EF 9  0
EF 11  0
EF 10  0
EF 9  0`

Comment: Have included `name='AB'` in the 1st CTE `ds` and the count of records are doubled (i.e.) all records appear twice

Comment: Also found the `lev` is not getting incremented.